# how to select the rows and use apply function on a list with elements of different length

Tags: r, list, dataframe

```
a <- list( G1 = data.frame(age = "8", gender = "M"), 
           G2 = data.frame(age = c("10","11"), gender = c("M", "F")), 
           G3 = data.frame(age = c("9","6"), gender = c("F", "F")) )
```

as shown, all variables input as character, then I wish to restore the `age` as numeric while keep `gender` as character. run the `lapply`, I got the result that really confused me. What's wrong?

```
lapply(a, function(x) {x[,1] <- as.numeric(x[,1])} )

$G1
[1] 1

$G2
[1] 1 2

$G3
[1] 2 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your approach you could convert the first column to numeric and then return the complete data frame back instead of just 1 column.

```
a[] <- lapply(a, function(x) {
    x[,1] <- as.numeric(as.character(x[,1]))
    x
})
```